# Atiyah's proof of the moduli space of SD irreducible YM connections

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, 4-manifolds, index-theory

In the paper "Self-duality in Four-dimensional Riemannian Geometry" (1978), Atiyah, Hitchin and Singer present a proof that the space of self-dual irreducible Yang-Mills connections is a Hausdorff manifold, and if it is not the empty set, then the dimension is given by
$$p_1(\text{Ad}(P))-\frac{1}{2}\dim G(\chi(M)-\tau(M))$$
Where $\chi(M)$ is the Euler characteristic and $\tau(M)$ the signature.

**EDIT:** It turns out the original paper contained an error/typo. It should in fact be
$$2p_1(\text{Ad}(P))-\frac{1}{2}\dim G(\chi(M)-\tau(M))$$
**End of edit.**

Although I would love to be able to understand the full paper, I am not in a position to be able to do so yet, I am only trying to understand the computation of this dimension, because I am interested in some applications of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem.
To compute this dimension, the following is utilised in the paper:
Let $D:\Gamma(V_-\otimes E)\to\Gamma(V_+\otimes E)$ be the Dirac operator for a spinor bundle with values in some auxiliary bundle $E$. By the index theorem,
$$\text{ind}(D)=\int_M\text{ch}(E)\widehat{A}(M)$$
In dimension four, we have $\widehat{A}(M)=1-\frac{1}{24}p_1(M)$ (but where is this used?). For the proof, we take $E=V_-\otimes\text{Ad}(P)$. Then $\text{ch}(E)=\text{ch}(\text{Ad}(P))\text{ch}(V_-)$. So far, so good. I lose track in the following computation:
$$\text{ind}(D)=\int_M\text{ch}(\text{Ad}(P))\text{ch}(V_-)\widehat{A}(M)\\
\color{red}{=p_1(\text{Ad}(P))+\dim G(\text{ind}(D'))}=\\
p_1(\text{Ad}(P))-\frac{1}{2}\dim G(\chi-\tau)$$
Where $D':\Gamma(V_+\otimes V_-)\to\Gamma(V_-\otimes V_-)$. I have been trying to find a result that explains the red coloured part of the equation, because this step seems completely non-trivial, and in spite of that, it is not elaborated upon within the paper at all, and I am not able to find any sources that explain this step. In [Index of Dirac operator and Chern character of symmetric product twisting bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351498/index-of-dirac-operator-and-chern-character-of-symmetric-product-twisting-bundle) the accepted answer seems to give an answer that goes some way towards explaining how this result is obtained, in a very particular case. However, I am not very experienced in this area and I don't know how to generalise the result to an arbitrary principal $G$-bundle. I am looking for an explanation of the above, whether someone is able to provide their own response or a reference. Either one would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hopefully I remember this well. My adviser explained this computation to me  I don't even want to think how many years ago.

The deformation complex  of the SD equation  is $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ad}{Ad}$

$$L=d_A^-\oplus d_A^*:\Omega^1\big(\, \Ad(P)\,\big)\to\Omega^2_-\big(\; \Ad(P)\;\big)\oplus \Omega^0\big(\;\Ad(P)\;\big). $$

The dimension of the moduli space of self-dual connections is the index of this operator. $\DeclareMathOperator{\ind}{ind}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{ch}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\hA}{\widehat{A}}$This operator is  obtained  by twisting with $\Ad(P)$  the   operator

$$ D=d^-+d^*:\Omega^1(M)\to \Omega^2_-(M)\oplus \Omega^0(M) $$

This is the operator $D: \Gamma(V_+\oplus V_-)\to \Gamma(V_-\oplus V_-)$ in the paper you mentioned.

The Atiyah-Singer index theory  shows  that $\ind L$ is

$$\ind L= \int_M \big[\; \ch(\Ad(P)) \hA(X)\ch(V_-)\;\big]_4, $$

where $[--]_4$ denotes the degree $4$  part of a non-homogeneous differential form.

We deduce

$$\ch(\Ad(P))=\dim G +\ch_2(\Ad(P))+\cdots = \dim G+p_1(\Ad(P))+\cdots, $$

$$\ind L= \int_M \big(\; p_1(\Ad(P))+(\dim G)\rho_D\;\big)  $$

where  the degree $4$ from $\rho_D= [\hA(X)\ch(V_-)]_4$ is the index density of $D$ appearing in the Atiyah-Singer index theorem
$$
\ind D=\int_M \rho_D.
$$

Thus

$$
\ind L=\int_M p_1(\Ad(P))+\dim G\ind D= \int_M p_1(\Ad(P))+\dim G(b_1 -b_2^--b_0). $$

Now express $(b_1-b_2^--b_0)$ in terms of the signature $\tau=b_2^+-b_2^-$ and the Euler characteristic $\chi=2b_0-2b_1+b_2^++b_2^-$.

Comment: Trying to go through your explanation in detail - I have one small question. You immediately write $\text{ch}(\text{Ad}(P))=\dim G+\text{ch}_2(\text{Ad}(P))+\dots$. Is it valid to immediately omit the first Chern character? Since we're taking the product with another term that contains degree $2$ forms, could it not combine with terms there to add a term to the index density? The only candidate for that term would be $\text{ch}(\text{Ad}(P))\text{ch}_1(V_-)$. I guess that this term has to vanish somehow?

Comment: $Ad(P)$ is a *real* vector bundle $c_1(Ad(P)\otimes \mathbb{C})=0$.

Comment: Final remark incoming. According to what I computed, we get the $\dim G$ term, and $\text{rank}V_-(-2c_2(\text{Ad}(P))=-4c_2(\text{Ad}(P))=p_1(\text{Ad}(P))$, so I am not sure if the mistake is on my end, but I thought I would point out the discrepancy between what I got and what you've posted (namely the sign of the Pontrjagin class and possibly some minor details in the Chern character of the adjoint bundle).

Comment: You do not need to know what $ch(V_-)$ is. (The computation of $ch(V_-)$ is tricky. The clincher is that $D=d_-+d^*$ and you know  what is the index $D$.

Comment: Although you've already helped me more than I could have hoped for, I made an edit to my original post explaining what I am talking about in more detail, because I think I did not make it clear (also the computation in my comment forgot about a factor of $1/2$). If you wouldn't mind, could you explain where the difference in our results comes from? Because your result seems to be off by a sign on the Pontrjagin class, whereas my result is off by a factor of $2$.

Comment: I had an error.  For a complex vector bundle $E$ $ch_2(E)=\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-2c_2)$ When $E=Ad(P)\otimes \mathbb{C}$ we get $ch_2(E)=-c_2(E)=p_1(Ad(P)$ (the last equality is the definition of $p_1$)

Comment: Ok! All clear then. I have deleted the remarks from my original post, as it seems clear the way it is now.

Comment: @QuaereVerum   Here is a subtility. On a compact oriented  $spin^c$ manifold $M$  the bundle $E=\Lambda^* T^*M\otimes \mathbb{C}$  and be identified with $End(V)$, where $V=V_+\oplus V_-$.  As such its admits two   $\mathbb{Z}/2$ gradings.  With one grading you get the Hodge-deRham operator with index Euler characteristic, and with another you get the signature operator.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment - holiday break. I would just like to remark that the factor of two which I mentioned is actually correct - Atiyah's original publication appears to have had a typo or error in it. I will edit the OP to make this clear.