# Exact formula for $\chi(X, \, S^n \Omega^1_X)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, chern-classes

I have a smooth, compact complex surface $X$, and I need an explicit formula for the Euler characteristic
$$\chi(X, \, S^n \Omega^1_X),$$
where $S^n$ denotes the symmetric product, in terms of $c_1(X), c_2(X)$.

I know how to do the computation, by using the splitting principle in order to calculate the Chern classes $c_i(S^n \Omega^1_X)$ and then the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch formula, and I did it for small values of $n$. However, extracting a formula for general $n$ seems quite tedious.

> **Question.** Is there a reference where I can find the value of  $\chi(X, \, S^n \Omega^1_X)$? Related to this: is there a reference
> for the Chern classes $c_1(S^n \Omega^1_X)$, $c_2(S^n \Omega^1_X)$?

Notice that I need an *exact* formula, not an asymptotic one (which I already know).

Comment: After a first attempt, I think $c_1(S^n\Omega_X^1) = \binom{n+1}{2}c_1(\Omega_X^1)$. I think I can also calculate $c_2(S^n\Omega_X^1)$, but I don't know a reference. Would a calculation suffice?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: If there is no reference, a calculation would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you may find useful Bogomolov's paper "Holomorphic symmetric tensors on projective surfaces".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you say, formulae for $c_1(\Omega_X^1)$ and $c_2(\Omega_X^1)$ can be obtained from the splitting principle. The following is a more general version of the calculation in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/351571/21564).

> **Lemma:** Let $V \to X$ be a rank two complex vector bundle. Then $c_1(S^nV) = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)c_1(V)$ and $c_2(S^nV) = \frac{1}{24}(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)c_1(V)^2 + \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(n+2)c_2(V)$.

**Proof:** By the splitting principle, there is a map $p : Y \to X$ such that $p^*$ is injective on integral cohomology and $p^*V \cong L_1\oplus L_2$, so $p^*(S^nV) \cong S^n(p^*V) \cong S^n(L_1\oplus L_2)$. In general, we have $S^n(E_1\oplus E_2) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n} S^i(E_1)\otimes S^j(E_2)$, but for a line bundle $L$ we have $S^k(L) = L^k$ (every tensor on a one-dimensional vector space is symmetric). Therefore

$$S^n(L_1\oplus L_2) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n} S^i(L_1)\otimes S^j(L_2) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n}L_1^i\otimes L_2^j \cong \bigoplus_{i=0}^nL_1^i\otimes L_2^{n-i},$$

so we have

\begin{align*} c_1(S^n(L_1\oplus L_2)) & = c_1\left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^nL_1^i\otimes L_2^{n-i}\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^nc_1(L_1^i\otimes L_2^{n-i})\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^nic_1(L_1) + (n-i)c_1(L_2)\\
&= \left(\sum_{i=0}^ni\right)c_1(L_1) + \left(\sum_{i=0}^nn-i\right)c_1(L_2)\\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)(c_1(L_1) + c_1(L_2))\\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)c_1(L_1\oplus L_2).\end{align*}

That is, $p^*(c_1(S^nV)) = p^*\left(\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)c_1(V)\right)$ so the claim for $c_1$ follows by the injectivity of $p^*$.

For $c_2$ we have

\begin{align*} 
&\, c_2(S^n(L_1\oplus L_2))\\ 
&=\, c_2\left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^nL_1^i\otimes L_2^{n-i}\right)\\
&=\, \sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq n}c_1(L_1^i\otimes L_2^{n-i})c_1(L_1^j\otimes L_2^{n-j})\\
&=\, \sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq n}(ic_1(L_1) + (n-i)c_1(L_2))(jc_1(L_1) + (n-j)c_1(L_2))\\
&=\, \sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq n}ijc_1(L_1)^2 + [i(n - j) + (n-i)j]c_1(L_1)c_1(L_2) + (n-i)(n-j)c_1(L_2)^2.\end{align*}

By writing $\displaystyle\sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq n}$ as $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}$ and using formulae for the sum of the first $k$ integers, squares, and cubes, one can show that

$$\sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq n}ij = \sum_{0\leq i < j \leq n}(n-i)(n-j) = \tfrac{1}{24}(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)$$

and

$$\sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq n}i(n-j)+(n-i)j = \tfrac{1}{12}n(n+1)(3n^2+n+2),$$

so

\begin{align*}
&\, c_2(S^n(L_1\oplus L_2))\\
&=\, \tfrac{1}{24}(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)(c_1(L_1)^2 + c_1(L_2)^2)\\ 
&\, \ \quad + \tfrac{1}{12}n(n+1)(3n^2+n+2)c_1(L_1)c_1(L_2)\\
&=\, \tfrac{1}{24}(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)(c_1(L_1)^2 + 2c_1(L_1)c_1(L_2) + c_1(L_2)^2)\\ 
&\, \ \quad + \left[\tfrac{1}{12}n(n+1)(3n^2+n+2) - 2\tfrac{1}{24}(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)\right]c_1(L_1)c_1(L_2)\\
&=\, \tfrac{1}{24}(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)(c_1(L_1) + c_1(L_2))^2\\
&\, \ \quad + \tfrac{1}{12}n(n+1)[3n^2+n+2-(n-1)(3n+2)]c_1(L_1)c_1(L_2)\\
&=\, \tfrac{1}{24}(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)c_1(L_1\oplus L_2)^2 + \tfrac{1}{6}n(n+1)(n+2)c_2(L_1\oplus L_2).\\
\end{align*}
As before, the claim for $c_2$ follows from the injectivity of $p^*$.$\quad\square$

Let $x_n$, $y_n$, and $z_n$ denote the expressions of $n$ in the formulae above so that $c_1(S^nV) = x_nc_1(V)$ and $c_2(S^nV) = y_nc_1(V)^2 + z_nc_2(V)$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{ch}(S^n\Omega_X^1) &= \operatorname{rank}(S^n\Omega_X^1) + c_1(S^n\Omega_X^1) + \tfrac{1}{2}(c_1(S^n\Omega_X^1)^2 - 2c_2(S^n\Omega_X^1))\\
&= \tbinom{n+2-1}{n} + x_nc_1(\Omega_X^1) + \tfrac{1}{2}(x_n^2c_1(\Omega_X^1)^2 - 2y_nc_1(\Omega_X^1)^2  -2z_nc_2(\Omega_X^1))\\
&= \tbinom{n+1}{n} - x_nc_1(X) + \tfrac{1}{2}(x_n^2c_1(X)^2 - 2y_nc_1(X)^2  -2z_nc_2(X))\\
&= n + 1 - x_nc_1(X) + \tfrac{1}{2}((x_n^2 - 2y_n)c_1(X)^2 - 2z_nc_2(X))
\end{align*}

so

\begin{align*}
&\, \chi(X, S^n\Omega_X^1)\\ 
&=\, \int_X\operatorname{ch}(S^n\Omega_X^1)\operatorname{Td}(X)\\
&=\, \int_X\left(n + 1 - x_nc_1(X) + \tfrac{1}{2}((x_n^2-2y_n)c_1(X)^2 - 2z_nc_2(X))\right)\cdot\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\left(1 + \tfrac{1}{2}c_1(X) + \tfrac{1}{12}(c_1(X)^2+c_2(X))\right)\\
&=\, \int_X\tfrac{1}{12}(n+1)(c_1(X)^2 + c_2(X)) -\tfrac{1}{2}x_nc_1(X)^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}((x_n^2-2y_n)c_1(X)^2 - 2z_nc_2(X))\\
&=\, \left(\tfrac{1}{12}(n+1) - \tfrac{1}{2}x_n + \tfrac{1}{2}(x_n^2-2y_n)\right)\int_Xc_1(X)^2 + \left(\tfrac{1}{12}(n+1) - z_n\right)\int_Xc_2(X)\\
&=\, \tfrac{1}{12}(n+1)(2n^2-2n+1)\int_Xc_1(X)^2 - \tfrac{1}{12}(n+1)(2n^2+4n-1)\int_Xc_2(X).\end{align*}

This can further be expressed in terms of the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$ and signature $\sigma(X)$ using the fact that $\int_Xc_1(X)^2 = 2\chi(X) + 3\sigma(X)$ and $\int_Xc_2(X) = \chi(X)$:

$$\chi(X, S^n\Omega_X^1) = \tfrac{1}{12}(n+1)(2n^2-8n+3)\chi(X) + \tfrac{1}{4}(n+1)(2n^2-2n+1)\sigma(X).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I checked your computations for $c_1(S^n V)$ and $c_2(S^n V)$. Regarding the computation of $\operatorname{ch}(S^n\Omega_X^1)$, you write $\operatorname{rank}(S^n \Omega^1_X) = \tbinom{n+2-1}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n}{2}$. However, it seems to me that this rank should be equal to $\tbinom{n+2-1}{n}= n+1$, which is the dimension of the graded $n$-piece in the polynomial ring $k[x, \, y]$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: No, you're correct. The dimension of the space of symmetric $n$-tensors on an $d$-dimensional vector space is $\tbinom{n+d-1}{n}$, so the dimension of the space of symmetric $n$-tensors on a two-dimensional vector space is $\tbinom{n+2-1}{n} = \tbinom{n+1}{n} = n+1$ as you say. I got the $d$ and $n$ mixed up, sorry about that. I will make the necessary corrections now. Hopefully our computations will then coincide.

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: I did the computations, too. The result I got is $$ \begin{align*}
&\, \chi(X, S^n\Omega_X^1)\\ 
&=\, \tfrac{1}{12}(n+1)(2n^2-2n+1)\int_Xc_1(X)^2 - \tfrac{1}{12}(n+1)(2n^2+4n-1)\int_Xc_2(X).\end{align*}$$ It agrees with the computations I separately made before  for small values of $n$ ($n=1, \, 2, \, 3, \, 4$ ). Our terms in $c_1^2$ differ.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: I checked my computation again, and I found an error: the term $-2y_n$ in the expression for the Chern character became $-y_n$ in the computation of $\chi(X, S^n\Omega_X^1)$. Putting in the missing factor of $2$ gives the same answer that you obtained - I will edit accordingly. Sorry for all the mistakes, you effectively had to do the computation on your own anyway.

Comment: Actually, your answer was precious despite the small typos. In particular, your computations of the two summatories involved in the Chern classes expressions really helped me.

Comment: +1 I wasn't convinced about your formula before because the leading coefficient differed from mine, but now  it does.

Comment: @DonuArapura: It's somewhat miraculous that the quartic terms cancel and the expression is cubic in $n$. I guess your answer explains why.

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference: using the `Schubert2` package from `Macaulay2` this can be quite effortlessly done.

```
i1 : needsPackage "Schubert2";

i2 : X = abstractVariety(2, QQ[n,c1,c2,Degrees=>{0,1,2}]);

i3 : T = abstractSheaf(X, Rank=>2, ChernClass=>1+c1+c2);

i4 : X.TangentBundle = T;

i5 : chi symmetricPower(n, cotangentBundle X)

              1 3  2   1 3      1    2   1 2      1  2   1        1
o5 = integral(-n c1  - -n c2 - --n*c1  - -n c2 + --c1  - -n*c2 + --c2)
              6        6       12        2       12      4       12
```

If one looks at the implementation, the $n$-th symmetric power of a bundle $\mathcal F$ is computed using the pushforward of the relative $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on the projectivization $\mathbf{P}(\mathcal F^\vee)$ (as already mentioned in the other answer).

Comment: Interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Following the method you indicate in your question,  if we let $x,y$ be the chern roots  then determining $c_2(Sym^{n} \Omega)$ corresponds to expanding $$\sum_{0 \leq i\neq i' \leq n} (ix + (n-i)y)(i'x + (n-i')y)$$ in terms of the symmetric functions  $xy$  (corresponding to $c_2(X)$) and $(x+y)^2$  (corresponding to $c_1(X)^2$).  It seems easier to use the function $x^2 + y^2$ instead of $(x+y)^2$  corresponding to $c_1(X)^2 - 2c_2(X)$.

Then we have to determine the two sums  $$\sum_{0\leq i\neq i' \leq n} ii'$$ and $$\sum_{0 \leq i \neq i' \leq n} i(n-i')+ i'(n-i).$$

There must be  more elegant ways of doing this,  but the brute force one is to argue that these are polynomials in $n$ of degree $4$ and compute enough values to determine them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Concerning the first part of the question, my initial recollection was that Miyaoka's  famous paper *On the Chern numbers of surfaces of general type* has the formulas you want. In fact, he doesn't quite have them, nevertheless his basic approach should give you the formula. Set $Y= \mathbb{P}(\Omega_X^1)$, with $L= \mathcal{O}_{Y}(1)$ the relative tautological bundle. Then the Leray spectral sequence, together with Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch and lemma 5 of Miyaoka  yields
$$\chi(X,S^n\Omega_X^1)= \chi(Y, L^n)= \int ch(L^n)\cdot todd(Y)$$
$$=\frac{n^3}{6}(c_1(X)^2-c_2(X)) + \ldots$$
Sorry, I'm too lazy to compute the rest, but hopefully that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you. This is the asymptotic formula I was talking about.