# Computation of $H^i(X, \, \operatorname{Sym}^n \Omega_X)$ for a surface of general type $(i=0, \, 1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $X$ be a smooth, complex surface of general type such that $\Omega_X$ is globally generated, and let $n \geq 2$ be a natural number.

> **Question.** Is there a way to compute $h^i(X, \, \operatorname{Sym}^n \Omega_X)$, where $i \in \{0, \, 1\}$, in terms of the invariants of $X$ (Chern numbers, geometric genus, irregularity, etc.)? Or, at least, is it possible to compute it under some additional assumptions (either on $X$ or on $n$)?

**Remark.** I know how to compute $\chi(X, \, \operatorname{Sym}^n \Omega_X)$, see [MO397682](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397682/exact-formula-for-chix-sn-omega1-x).